# Web.config separate customHeaders section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-config

I'd like to separate my `Web.config` file, specifically the `customHeaders` section of `system.webServer -> httpProtocol`. I've tried replacing

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By"></remove>
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"></add>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

with

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders configSource="WebConfigShards/CustomHeaders.config" >
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But apparently `configSource` attribute is not supported here. Is there any other solution to this issue beside loading custom file via code from app start?

Comment: If you manage your custom headers using an `HttpModule` then that class can get the header names and values from anywhere. You don't have to write custom file handling. You could just create a simple custom configuration section which you can load using `ConfigurationManager`, and then you can split that section into a separate file using `configSource`.